# Adaptive Payment PAY returns status COMPLETED everytime

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

in my app im using PayPal-sandbox adaptive payment PAY method. Problem is in incoming IPN message. Everytime I get 'completed' status of payment. Even if in my paypal account interface is 'unclaimed' status.

Somewhere I read, that paypal should send 'pending' status. And if I accept the payment, paypal send me next ipn message with status 'completed'... otherwise status 'denied'. Is it right?

Can somebody explain me, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the status you would see for an Unclaimed payment. The overall Pay call is "completed" as there were no errors and the money left the sender account. If you'd like to get individual transaction statuses (if you are the API caller) then you would use the PaymentDetails call.